# Apache PDFBox - Need Help Reading a Form

Tags: java, apache, pdfbox

I am trying to read a PDF form using the Apache PDFBox. As I figured, if I use the PDFTextStripper it retrieves the text not the form data. How do I read the form data that is entered in the PDF? I have just a few fields to read and they are simple String and number.

Thanks!

Update: I tried the following code:

```
    PDDocumentCatalog catalog = pd.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDAcroForm form = catalog.getAcroForm();

    if (form == null) {
        System.out.println("No form...stop");
        return;
    }

    List<PDField> fields = new ArrayList<PDField>();
    fields = form.getFields();
    log.info("---Fields Size:"+fields.size());

    for(int i=0;i<fields.size();i++) {
        log.info("i:"+i);
        PDField field = (PDField) fields.get(i);
        String value = field.getValue();
        String name = field.getFullyQualifiedName();
        log.info("name:"+name);
     }
```

This gives me the output:  name:topmostSubform[0]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23497324/using-pdfbox-to-get-form-field-values

Comment: @SwatiSinghal have you tried to output the value instead of the name?